# Assign decreasing weights inside a in binary masks - python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a set of binary masks,the masks contain several single objects ( not connected to each other ) and I need to assign the pixels inside those white regions,  some weights that decrease ( from a certain value in the boundary to one in the center ) as I move inside the mask. So I'm wondering how I can achieve this.

So far what I have thought is to move row by row in the image, finding the connected white regions ( inside the mask ) and once I'd found those regions,  apply some mathematical functions ( lets say a quadratic function ) to calculate the weights ( the exact value of those is not so important, but there has to be a difference as I go deeper inside the mask) But I think this may not be the best way to implement it. 
Other idea I have is, find the center of each one of those white regions, and use it as a central point for a gaussian distribution. I need this calculation to be efficient as I have to run it many times.

Any idea on how to solve this? I'm trying to do this for a image classification problem,I think that assigning weights to the pixels may help to improve accuracy.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what is your intent... what about [Distance transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm)?

Comment: I believe that distance transform is what I need . I'm gonna check it out.